# Is there a comprehensive list of languages?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, languages

Is there a more comprehensive list of basic non-Golarian languages in Pathfinder than the one found in the [Linguistics skill's description](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/linguistics.html)?

Comment: When you say "non-Golarian" languages, are you seeking only Core Rulebook languages?  Or languages that are in other supplements yet specifically not in the Golarian setting?  Or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/linguistics)  lists thirty-four languages, more than the twenty-one that are referenced under the paizo.com site:

1. Aboleth
2. Abyssal
3. Aklo
4. Aquan ("Tongue of the Sea")
5. Auran ("Tongue of the Heavens")
6. Boggard
7. Celestial
8. Common
9. Cyclops
10. Dark Folk
11. Draconic
12. Drow Sign Language
13. Druidic
14. Dwarven
15. D’ziriak
16. Elven
17. Giant
18. Gnoll
19. Gnome
20. Goblin
21. Grippli
22. Halfling
23. Ignan ("Tongue of Fire")
24. Infernal
25. Necril
26. Orc
27. Protean
28. Sphinx
29. Sylvan
30. Tengu
31. Terran ("Tongue of Earth")
32. Treant
33. Undercommon
34. Vegepygmy

If you are like me, and you like to dig into the guts of your PCGen installation, you can see all twenty-one languages that come with the core rulebook along with "Read Lips."   This would make twenty-two languages.

The command:

```
grep TYPE  /Applications/PCGen\ 6.04.00.app/Contents/Resources/Java/data/pathfinder/paizo/roleplaying_game/core_rulebook/cr_languages.lst
```

Gives the output:

```
Abyssal TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Planar
Aklo        TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Aquan       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Elemental
Auran       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Elemental
Celestial   TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Planar
Common  TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Draconic    TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Druidic TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read        PREVAREQ:DruidSecretLanguage,1
Dwarven TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Elven       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Giant       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Gnoll       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Gnome       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Goblin  TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Halfling    TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Ignan       TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Elemental
Infernal    TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Planar
Orc     TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Sylvan  TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Terran  TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read.Elemental
Undercommon TYPE:Spoken.Written.Read
Read Lips   TYPE:Spoken
```

The command:

```
grep -c  TYPE  /Applications/PCGen\ 6.04.00.app/Contents/Resources/Java/data/pathfinder/paizo/roleplaying_game/core_rulebook/cr_languages.lst
```

Outputs:

```
22
```

This example above searches through an installation of PCGen on Mac OS X by opening iTerm2 and the `grep` command.  Other installations on other platforms should work similarly using similar tools.

Answer (score 3):

There are 126 languages currently available from all first party Paizo supplements when you include the Golarion specific languages. I can tell this from my Hero Lab software, but I'm not sure there's a completely comprehensive list elsewhere, though most are reflected on [the Golarion Wiki's language page](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Languages_of_Golarion).

Comment: that sounds like a requirement you should add to your question.

Comment: Yes, yes it does